# The property of positive fourier series.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

This is the problem in the book 'Classical and multilinear harmonic analysis, volume 1'

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}[a_{n}\cos{2\pi nx}+b_{n}\sin{2\pi nx}]$ be a nonnegative function defiend on $[0,1]$. Show that there exists an complex sequence $\{c_{n} \}_{n=0}^{N}$ such that
$$f(x)=|\sum_{n=0}^{N}c_{n}e^{2\pi inx}|^2$$

I have no idea. How can we use the property that $f$ is a positive function?